# How can apply multiple filter in checkboxlist using code behind

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

```
<div class="filter">
        <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text="Product"></asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryTitle" DataValueField="CategoryTitle"></asp:CheckBoxList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Product%>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProdustId], [ProductTitle] FROM [ProductMaster] WHERE ID=1 "></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>

    <div class="filter">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTopic" runat="server" Text="Topic"></asp:Label>

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryTitle" DataValueField="CategoryTitle"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Product%>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProdustId], [ProductTitle] FROM [ProductMaster] WHERE ID=2 "></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <asp:Label ID="lblContentType" runat="server" Text="Content Type"></asp:Label>

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryTitle" DataValueField="CategoryTitle"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Product%>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProdustId], [ProductTitle] FROM [ProductMaster] WHERE ID=3"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

I want to apply multi selected and multi level filter on product and company so that price will show accordingly. If any one select product(Laptop) name then only Laptop ->Company name show under Company column and then Price will show according to the selected company.

Please help guide me. I am unbale to attach output. Below is the out with checkbox

```
Product   Name Company  Price
Laptop    Toshiba      37000
Mobile    Asus         2000
Tab       Nokia        3000
```

Comment: use asp:CheckBoxList SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: build your query based on the values selected

Comment: Thanks for feedback, What will be the sql query for this ?

Comment: EX:`select Name_company,price from PrductMaster where product='Laptop'`